# Android - Vertical align of Listview row content

Tags: android, listview, row, alignment

I can't align the content of ListView rows vertically on middle.

Screenshot of Listview:

[image: Screenshot of Listview]

[Its my Listview row layout](http://pastebin.com/g4ak6qmm)

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <Button android:id="@+id/open"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:text="Open"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/check"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@id/open"
            />

    <TextView android:text="@+id/label"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/label"
              android:textSize="16px"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@id/check"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```